# No qualifying bean of type 'tn.esen.dao.StudentRepository' available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, repository, javabeans

i'm developing a crud application with SPRING and as usual, I faced a problem saying that no qualifying beans is available and didn't even add the student table in the database.

this is the problem:

> Exception in thread "main" org.spring framework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'tn.esen.dao.StudentRepository' available

entity:

```
package tn.esen.entity;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;


@Entity
@Table(name="etud")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String nom;
    
    private String prenom;
    
    private Double moyenne;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public Double getMoyenne() {
        return moyenne;
    }

    public void setMoyenne(Double moyenne) {
        this.moyenne = moyenne;
    }

    public Student() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

controller:

```
package tn.esen.control;


import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import tn.esen.dao.StudentRepository;
import tn.esen.entity.Student;


@Controller
public class MycontrolStudent {

    @Autowired
    public StudentRepository metier;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public String home(Model mymodel) {
        
        //importing the list of all students
        List<Student> allstudents= metier.findAll();
        //adding an attribute to the model contain the list of students
        mymodel.addAttribute("listestudent",allstudents);
        return ("acceuil");
        
    }
}
```

repository:

```
package tn.esen.dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import tn.esen.entity.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student,Long> {
    
}
```

main program:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import tn.esen.dao.StudentRepository;
import tn.esen.entity.Student;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx =  SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        
        StudentRepository StudentRepository = ctx.getBean(StudentRepository.class);
        
        
        List<Student> allstud = StudentRepository.findAll();
         System.out.println("--------------------list of students-----------------------");
         
         for(Student stud:allstud) {
             System.out.println(stud); 
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `StudentRepository` is in a complete different package: `tn.esen.dao`
You should add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "tn.esen")`
to your `DemoApplication.java`